# How to generate a form from a database in an android app?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to build an android application for a "school" on which students could take tests, I thought that the teachers could submit their tests (questions, and answers,...) via a web application after that the students can retrive the forms to take the test and submit their answers via my app.
my question is how to generate forms from a distant database (mysql in this case)?

Comment: First question: **What have you tried?**

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this because the UI are (as far as I know) xml files...

Answer (score 1):

Databases store primitive types, like strings, decimals, etc. I don't think a database is what you want for this application.  Without knowing how you plan to create and store the forms, its impossible to comment on how they should be retrieved.  There are tons of ways you can create the form and store it.  So once you've made those decisions, we can help you with recommendations on how to retrieve forms.

Comment: Well I think of it like this: the questions table contains five columns (type string) the first column would be the question it self, second one would be the first answer, an so on... how can I retrive a set of questions in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of anything that will do what you're describing but here's something that might be able to help point you in the direction:

[Generate Android Form from JSON Schema](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/04/android-form-generator/)